# Multiple sets of radio buttons on the same Artboard

Tags: adobe-xd

Can we have multiple radio buttons sets on the SAME artboard?

Example:

- Buy a bicycle
- Sell a bicycle

Condition

- New
- Used

If the user chooses "Sell a bicycle" and then he chooses "New" and then he changed his mind and chooses "Used", then he chooses "Buy a bicycle", etc... How can we save the last chosen option in a set without losing the last chosen option in the other set?

Answer (score 0):

Preface: I don't know AdobeXD.

As with any HTML radio button group, when only one option is to be selected, the **name attribute** controls the grouping. So, radio buttons with identical `name="something"` will toggle each other *without* toggling *other* button groups.

From merely looking at the question, it would seem what is needed are two *separate* names - one for each of the two groups of radio buttons.

```
<input type="radio" name="buy_sell" value="buy" /> Buy a Bicycle
<input type="radio" name="buy_sell" value="sell" /> Sell a Bicycle

Condition
<input type="radio" name="new_used" value="new" /> New
<input type="radio" name="new_used" value="used" /> Used
```

Comment: True for HTML, but Adobe XD is just for mockups and it is code independent. For every single change there is a new screen. My problem relies in multiple actions in the same screen, that means 2 x 2 = 4 screens in total unless there's another way around that I am not aware of.